# how to send data from mongodb to the get method in express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to access the data from mongodb and send it to the get method in express js. I am able to acess the data but not able to send it to the get method.
here is my code

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.send('this is test for mongo db');

 Person.find(function(err, response){
   var data = response;
   console.log(data);
   res.send(data);
 });
});
```

here console.log(data is working) but res.send(data) is not working. any sugessions ?

Comment: You've already sent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> res.send used to send response to client , it is only used once .

use res.send once , in your code you have used res.send twice

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){

 Person.find(function(err, response){
     if(err){
       console.log(err)  
       return res.send('error');      
     }

     if(!err && response){
       console.log(response)
       res.send(response);
     } 
   });
});
```